# How to set \framed to make the baseline of the whole \framed as same as the first line in this \framed in ConTeXt?

Tags: boxes, context, framed

An simple example:

```
\starttext
\setupframed[align=right,frame=off,offset=none]
\framed{A\hskip3em\framed{B\\ C}}
\stoptext
```

How can I set the `framed` which contains `B\\ C` so that the baseline of `\framed{B\\ C}` can have the same baseline with the first line `B`?

The same result can be achieved in plain TeX as follows:

```
\hbox{\vtop{\hbox{A}}\hskip3em\vtop{\hbox{B}\hbox{C}}}
```

What's the method in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `location=top`, see [Wiki - setupframed](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupframed) for more options.

```
\starttext
  \framed{A\hskip3em\framed[align=normal,location=top]{B\\ C}}
\stoptext
```

[image: result]